# Read attribute names and return attribute information from dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, attributes

I am trying to write a simply query that will return all the attributes requested. The idea is to read the attributes names and return attribute information. It should start with the string 'select' and then followed by a list of the attributes the user wants to see

So, there is a small database consisting of dictionaries:

```
dsql_table = 
[{'name': 'Jan', 'type': 'man', 'profession': 'Analyst'},
{'name': 'Max', 'type': 'man', 'profession': 'Doctor'}]
```

And the idea is to only implement the functionality (disregarding error handling):

```
try:
    query = input('dsql> ')

    while query != 'exit':

# I need to implement code over here

print ('Thank you!')
```

How can I do this without using classes? So if one input e.g. 'select name type', then it should return 'michiel man
Jan man'.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to get the attribute names from the query, then it's quite simple.

```py
dsql_table = [
    {'name': 'Jan', 'type': 'man', 'profession': 'Analyst'},
    {'name': 'Max', 'type': 'man', 'profession': 'Doctor'},
]

query = 'select name type'

# extract selected attributes from query
selected_attributes = query.split()[1:]

result = []

for record in dsql_table:

    # iterate over selected attributes, store value if attribute exists
    for attribute in selected_attributes:
        if attribute in record:
            result.append(record[attribute])

# now result is a list ['Jan', 'man', 'Max', 'man']

print(' '.join(result))
```

Alternatively, `result` can be populated using a list comprehesion:

```py
result = [
    record[attribute]
    for record in dsql_table
    for attribute in selected_attributes
    if attribute in record
]
```

Comment: Thank you for your quick response. It almost works perfect. However, If I input 'name' only, the output should be 'Jan, Max'. If I input 'name, profession', the output should be 'Jan analyst Max Doctor'. Right now it only returns the information of the last last entered attribute. e.g. when entering 'name, profession', it gives 'analyst doctor'. Do you know how I can fix this? Thank you in advance

Comment: If you use comma in the query, e.g. `select name, profession`, the first attribute will be treated as `name,` and will not be found. The query should be `select name profession` for the above code to work.

Comment: Great! And if I want to use a class instead of a list of dictionaries, would you mind elaborating on how I can design this? 

I was thinking about this:

```
 class query: 
    def __init__(self,name,type,profession):

            
        self.name = name
        self.last = type
        self.pay = learning_type
 ```

I am not sure how to continue. Thanks in advance

Comment: If the individual records are objects of a custom class, and if they are stored in the same list called `dsql_table`, all you would do is replace `record[attribute]` with `getattr(record, attribute)`, and replace `if attribute in record` with `if hasattr(record, attribute)`.